# Java - Как подключить Tesseract?

Tags: java, apache, изображения, tesseract

Пробую извлечь картинку из документа пока использую pdf, но в планах брать любой другой формат.

Использую такой код:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filename);

        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);

        TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
        PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

        parseContext.set(TesseractOCRConfig.class, config);
        parseContext.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
        parseContext.set(Parser.class, parser); // need to add this to make
                                                // sure recursive parsing
                                                // happens!
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, parseContext);
        String text = handler.toString().trim();
```

Добавил такую зависимость:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Скачал tess4j-3.0.0.jar отсюда: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/?source=typ_redirect
Установил, потом добавил путь к файлу в переменную среды PATH, при этом в коде высвечиваются предупреждения на строчках:

```
TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
```

Что не удается найти такие классы.

Подскажите как их подключить? Может надо сделать что-то еще? Подскажите как быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.25</version>
</dependency>
```